# Clarification of how to use Stokes' Theorem if you are not given a Vector Field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am working on a few surface integrals in preparation for an exam and one question specifically states to use Stokes' Theorem to solve, however, rather than giving a vector field, we are given a differential two-form. I know the generalized Stokes'-Cartan Theorem, but this problem specifically states to use just Stokes' Theorem. Is this possible? If so, how?

The question I'm specifically working on is to evaluate:
$$ \int_{S_2}z\ dy\ dz $$
where $S_2$ is the intersection between $S$ the unit sphere and $z\le1$. I am thinking that the boundary will be the part of the sphere below $z=1$ plus the circle at $z=1$ with radius $r=\sqrt3$. I'm not sure if this is right, however, as in the vector calculus version of Stokes' Theorem, it relates a surface integral to a line integral. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've never heard of the Stokes-Cartan Theorem. But your question is asking for the flux of the vector field $\vec F = (z,0,0)$ across the surface.

Comment: How do you know that is the related vector field, i.e. how do you know the vector field is given by $(z,0,0)$ rather than say $(0,z,0)$ or $(0,0,z)$?

Comment: To my knowledge, Stokes-Cartan Theorem gives $\int_{\partial M}\omega=\int_{M} d\omega$ where $M$ is some manifold of $n$ dimension and $\omega$ is a differential $n-1$ form.

Comment: My original thought of how to approach this was to use the fact that this intersection is the boundary of some ball. Then $d\omega=0$ the integral equals $0$ but I am unsure if this is even possible given the specification to use Stokes' rather than the Theorem I stated above.

Comment: Because your text/course should show that the flux of $\vec F=(M,N,P)$ turns into integral of the $2$-form $M\,dy\wedge dz + N\,dz\wedge dx + P\,dx\wedge dy$. (You might find my [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) useful. For this, look at MATH 3510 day 35. The course uses differential forms, but there are lots of examples.)

Comment: It's easier to use the fact that your surface has a boundary curve. If you want to form a volume (and take $d\omega$), you'll need to add a disk to the bottom of the surface and apply Stokes's Theorem to the $3$-dimensional region bounded by the spherical shell *and* the disk.

Comment: Wow thank you so much I will definitely take a look!

Comment: The disk being at $z=1$ and the shell being the part of the sphere below this?

Comment: Oops. I didn't read carefully enough. You're right: The disk goes at the top :)